# Asp.Net Telerik RadDataPager Previous button rendering onclick return false

Tags: asp.net, telerik, raddatapager

I'm trying to use the Asp.Net Telerik RadDataPager with my own server side custom paging (I have millions of rows so need to manage this myself). The Next and Last buttons are firing and I can show the relevant page of data in my grid, but the Previous and First buttons are not firing. When I inspect the rendered HTML it shows onclick as returning false.

```
<input id="WebUserControl11_RadDataPager1_ctl00_PrevButton" class="rdpPagePrev" type="submit" onclick="return false;" value=" " name="WebUserControl11$RadDataPager1$ctl00$PrevButton">
```

If I remove the OnClick with FireBug then the button fires and I can handle it server side.

Any idea how I can get the RadDataPager to render without the OnClick?

Thanks

Comment: Okay I sussed it. My grid control has a built in pager, I don't need to use a separate RadDataPager control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I sussed it. My grid control has a built in pager, I don't need to use a separate RadDataPager control.